# Country detection in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, country

I use Google Analytics (GA for abbreviation) in an iOS app I create and I have a question about "Country" dimension in GA.
If a user use my app in US and then travel to UK and use my app again, to which "Country" do this user belong in GA ? Is that UK ?

I want to find what kind of action do these 'travelers' take in my app, and I hope I can find out how to select a "User Segment" where my app is used in US and also in UK?

Answer (score 0):

The dimension is based on the IP address that's sending the data to GA.